# Does AWS Sagemaker PySparkProcessor manage autoscaling?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, sdk, amazon-sagemaker

I'm using Sagemaker to generate to do preprocessing and generate training data and I'm following the Sagemaker API documentation [here](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/amazon_sagemaker_processing.html#pysparkprocessor), but I don't see any way currently how to specify autoscaling within the EMR cluster. What should I include within the `configuration` argument that I pass to my spark_processor `run()` object? What shouldn't I include?

I'm aware of the [this resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html), but it doesn't seem comprehensive.

Below is my code; it is very much a "work-in-progress", but I would like to know if someone could provide me with or point me to a resource that shows:

1. Whether this PySparkProcessor object will manage autoscaling automatically. Should I put AutoScaling config within the `configuration` in the `run()` object?
2. An example of the full config that I can pass to the `configuration` variable.

Here's what I have so far for the configuration.

```
SPARK_CONFIG = \
    { "Configurations": [
          {   "Classification": "spark-env",
              "Configurations": [ {"Classification": "export"} ] }
        ] 
    }

spark_processor = PySparkProcessor(
    tags=TAGS,
    role=IAM_ROLE,
    instance_count=2,
    py_version="py37",
    volume_size_in_gb=30,
    container_version="1",
    framework_version="3.0",
    network_config=sm_network,
    max_runtime_in_seconds=1800,
    instance_type="ml.m5.2xlarge",
    base_job_name=EMR_CLUSTER_NAME,
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
)

spark_processor.run(
    configuration=SPARK_CONFIG,
    submit_app=LOCAL_PYSPARK_SCRIPT_DIR,
    spark_event_logs_s3_uri="s3://{BUCKET_NAME}/{S3_PYSPARK_LOG_PREFIX}",
)
```

I'm used to interacting via Python more directly with EMR for these types of tasks. Doing that allows me to specify the entire EMR cluster config at once--including applications, autoscaling, EMR default and autoscaling roles--and then adding the steps to the cluster once it's created; however, much of this config seems to be abstracted away, and I don't know what remains or needs to be specified, specifically regarding the following config variables:  `AutoScalingRole`, `Applications`, `VisibleToAllUsers`, `JobFlowRole`/`ServiceRole` etc.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in the [Sagemaker Python SDK github](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/spark/processing.py).

```
    _valid_configuration_keys = ["Classification", "Properties", "Configurations"]
_valid_configuration_classifications = [
    "core-site",
    "hadoop-env",
    "hadoop-log4j",
    "hive-env",
    "hive-log4j",
    "hive-exec-log4j",
    "hive-site",
    "spark-defaults",
    "spark-env",
    "spark-log4j",
    "spark-hive-site",
    "spark-metrics",
    "yarn-env",
    "yarn-site",
    "export",
]
```

Thus, specifying autoscaling, Visibility, and some other cluster level configurations seems not to be supported. However, the applications installed upon cluster start up seem to depend on the applications in the above list.